# Style HTML5 progress tag that reached it's maximum value

Tags: css, html, progress-bar

Is it possible to style a progressbar that reached its max-value differently in CSS than the one that hasn't started yet or is started?

for example doing something like

```
progress[max=value] {
background: green // color when maxed out
}
progress {
background: red;//default color
}
```

Or do I have to use Javascript to detect it?

Comment: Why can't you check the value of progress bar and add CSS class if it is 100%?

Comment: @GurpreetSingh - AIUI there's no requirement that the `max` of a `progress` element is 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that we know the maximum value of the progress bar. I'm going to use the following markup:

```html
<progress max=100 value=100></progress>
```

Our progress bar here has a maximum value of 100 and a value of 100, meaning it is at its completed state. From this we can use the [[att=val] selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) to target it at its completed state:

```css
progress[value="100"] { ... }
```

Chris Coyier has an [article on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/) which explains how the `progress` element can be styled in Chrome, Firefox and IE10. Following this we can apply the styling to the completed progress bar. First we reset the style:

```css
progress[value="100"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Then we can specifically apply styling to `::-webkit-progress-value` and `::-moz-progress-bar` to target the foreground progress bar on both Chrome and Firefox. For this I'm setting a background colour of `#f00` (red):

```css
/* Chrome */
progress[value="100"]::-webkit-progress-value {
    background:#f00;
}

/* Firefox */
progress[value="100"]::-moz-progress-bar {
    background:#f00;
}
```

Finally we can add in the IE10 styling by simply adding a `color` property on the main selector:

```css
progress[value="100"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

    /* IE10 */
    color:#f00;
}
```

Here is a [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/QNr75/1/) demonstrating this with two progress bars - the first at 50% and the second at 100%. For the lazy, here is the result across Chrome, Firefox and IE10:

[image: Chrome, Firefox and IE10 Progress Bar Result]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, to bad I do not know the max values of the progress bars. I could calculated them of course

Comment: Nice, it even works when `value` is updated dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/AFzYU/2/ To bad that it works only for pre-defined maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to see some pseudo class for finished state of the `<progress>` element, because the browser (both Chrome and Firefox on OS X) already knows when it's finished and changes the appearance accordingly.

Unfortunately, the only pseudo class `<progress>` seems to support is `:indeterminate`, that is `value` has not been set.

You can of course use JavaScript and add some class on your own (but you can't even listen for `change` event on `<progress>`):

```
var progress = document.querySelector('progress');

// then somewhere inside a callback

if (progress.value === progress.max) {
    progress.classList.add('finished');
} else {
    progress.classList.remove('finished');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AFzYU/

Comment: Yes I think this is currently the best option available, tobad it's not yet possible to do it 100% in css

Comment: @RobbertStevens Somebody should open a request for this.